# Vue-Bootstrap Component with exact width

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have an issue with **bootstrap-vue navitem**. I cannot set the **witdh** of the  **components**, therefore when I change the language of my website the navbar items jump around.

This is what it looks like:

[Language 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHOj7.png)
[Language 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUywz.png)

The code looks like this  and i tried adjusting the width with element, then I added a class and still nothing happened

```
      <b-nav-item right href="/">
          {{ $t("header.Login_Header") }}
      </b-nav-item>

      <b-nav-item right href="/">
          {{ $t("header.Register_Header") }}
      </b-nav-item>

      <b-nav-item right href="/">
        {{ $t("header.LoginUser_Header") }}
      </b-nav-item>

        <b-nav-item right href="/"
        @click="logout">
          {{ $t("header.Logout_Header") }}
      </b-nav-item>

    </b-navbar-nav>


b-navbar-item{
    width: 5%;
}
```

Any help would be nice.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Code examples? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is my first question here, and I have got a suggestion, that I should remove the codes, so I did. But it is back again.

Comment: Your CSS rule has to target a valid html element, not a `component`.

Comment: Thank you Micael. This solved my problem. I had to style my **li** element.

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer if you add it as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass styles to components (they will get applied to the root element of the component)

```html
<b-nav-item right href="/" :style="{ minWidth: '20rem' }">
  {{ $t("header.Login_Header") }}
</b-nav-item>
```

You could also createa custom class and apply it:

```css
.my-nav-item {
  min-width: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<b-nav-item right href="/" class="my-nav-item">
  {{ $t("header.Login_Header") }}
</b-nav-item>
```